# How to make a Setting of list of values depend on the value of a task

Tags: sbt

I want to set a `SettingKey[Seq[Tuple2[String, String]]]` called `IzPack.variables` of a 3rd party plugin called [sbt-izpack](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-izpack/).

The documentation tells how to set this setting:

```
IzPack.variables in IzPack.Config <+= name {name => ("projectName", name)}
```

I think that the `<+=` syntax is old.  There is no explanation about it in the `0.13.5` SBT documentation.

How can I append values that depends on tasks?

This is the syntax I'm using now:

```
IzPack.variables in IzPack.Config ++= Seq(
    ("appVersion", mySetting1.value),
    ("cocoonXconf", mySetting2.value),
)
```

but it complains when trying to use a task value with this message:

```
A setting cannot depend on a task
```

Comment: Confirmed that `<+=`  syntax is old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've finally done is to refactor my own code, so that a task that generates a file, is split in a setting that defines the output file, and a task that creates the file contents.

The setting is used for initializing the setting `IzPack.variables`, whereas my custom task is made dependant of the task that uses `IzPack.variables`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `Setting` it must be known at project load as `Setting`s are only computed once. `Tasks` on the other hand are computed each time. A `Setting` can not depend on a `Task` but a `Task` can depend on a `Setting`.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/More-About-Settings.html#Tasks+with+dependencies.